# Use, in child directive, value from parent directive and $scope

Tags: angularjs

**EXAMPLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/r2zvreL8/1/

I have two directives, parent and child, applied as:

```
<div parent parent-model="model">
  <div child>Child</div>
</div>
```

I need child to access parent-model value. So I have:

```
angular.module("app").directive("parent", parent);

function parent() {

  var parent = {
    controller: ["$scope", controller],
    link: link,
    replace: false,      
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return parent;

  function controller($scope) {
    $scope.model = "model";
  } 

  function link(scope, element, attributes) { } 

}
```

And I created the child as follows:

```
angular.module("app").directive("child", child);

function child() {

  var child = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,      
    restrict: "A"
  };

  return child;

  function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) { 
    // NEED parent-model value here.
    console.log(controller.model); // Returns undefined
  } 

}
```

I tried a few options to make this work but no luck ...

1. How to define $scope.model in parent from attributes.model?
2. How to access controller (parent) scope in child link?

At least I think this is what I need to do right?

Comment: Since child is not creating isolated scope, you can access parent data in the link function of child as scope is inherited. `scope.model` does not work?

Comment: To be honest I got lost with you answer ... I tried many options but there is always something going wrong ... Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: ` function link(scope, element, attributes, controller) { 
    scope.model // does not work?
  } `

Comment: You can use `require` in child directive. Example `var child = {
    link: link, require:"parent"...` and then in function `link` use parameter `controller`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko I tried that but returns undefined ... Check my updated answer: console.log(controller.model);

Comment: @Chandermani yes, scope.model in child returns the value ... But how to define model in parent based on attribute parent-model="model"?

Comment: You need define `scope` in parent model. I'm create jsfiddle.

Comment: I am a liitle bit lost! I am able now to get the scope in child variable but I am using $scope in parent which I am not sure it is the best option ... And I am still not able to define scope.model from parent-model attribute. I just created an example: http://jsfiddle.net/r2zvreL8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses the `$parent`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/zs4a66kz/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
      x: 2
    };
  })
  .directive("parent", parent)
  .directive("child", child);

function parent() {

  var parent = {
    controller: controller,
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      parentModel: "="
    }
  };

  return parent;

  function controller($scope) {
    console.log('parent', $scope.parentModel);
  }

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {}

}

function child() {

  var child = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A",
  }
  return child;

  function controller($scope) {}

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
    console.log('child link', scope.$parent.parentModel);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <span parent parent-model="model">
      <div child>Child</div>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution using `controllerAs` syntax.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ux542f8w/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
      x: 2
    };
  })
  .controller('ParentController', function() {
    console.log('parent', this);
  })
  .directive("parent", parent)
  .directive("child", child);

function parent() {

  var parent = {
    controller: "ParentController",
    controllerAs: "pr",
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    template: "<span ng-transclude></span>",
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      parentModel: "="
    },
    bindToController: true,
  };

  return parent;


  function link(scope, element, attributes) {}

}

function child() {

  var child = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A",
    require: "^parent"
  }
  return child;


  function link(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
    console.log('child link', ctrl);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <span parent parent-model="model">
      <div child>Child</div>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope properties to create two way binding between a variable inside the directive scope and the parent controller as defined in attributes.

```
     scope: {model: '=model'}
```

For your second question, the answer is straightforward. Your directive scope prototypical inherit from it's parent scope as long as the directive doesn't create an isolated scope.

In the snippets you have given,

```
console.log(scope.model)
```

in the second link function should give you access to the `model` variable in the parent scope.

A nice trick is that `$parent` is still available as a reference to parent scope even if you create an isolated scope.

Comment: But what is the difference between using model="=model" and $scope? I wasn't able to make your code work. I created an example in http://jsfiddle.net/r2zvreL8/1/. Could you, please, give a more complete example? you can for mine. Thank You

Comment: Follow this tutorial first http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/